# Is it legitimate to ask co-workers to use specific browser in an intranet website?

Tags: web-development, user-experience, browser-compatibility

I developed an intranet (local network) `ASP.NET` web project for my co-workers.

In the development process I used `Chrome` and `Firefox` and didn't test much with `Internet Explorer`.

The website works well with `Firefox` and `Chrome` and with `IE` it had major bugs.

**Is it legitimate to ask the users to use `Chrome` or `Firefox`?**

They are all co-workers (around 15 users).

I don't want to spend time fixing the bugs for `IE`, some might be related to stuff I can't fix myself (`jQuery` things), if I wanted to be compatible with all browsers, I would have to make a major re-design,

Comment: jquery is meant to be as cross browser compatible as possible (including IE), it's likely not the cause

Comment: @ratchetfreak, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942327/jquery-validation-not-working-in-ie7-ie8
There are some issues with IE and Jquery remote-val

Comment: Keep calm and close IE -- http://sd.keepcalm-o-matic.co.uk/i/keep-calm-and-close-ie.png

Comment: Next time, ask them *first* and *then* develop.

Comment: How would you feel yourself if you were forced to use IE for an intranet site?

Comment: @Ofiris That seems to have been due to incompatibility between a third-party JQuery plugin and a newer version of JQuery, not an actual bug in JQuery.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments, udnerstood it is legitimate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see a problem to set a single supported browser for small intranet applications, if using that browser is within company policy. Ironing out all the little problems with all browsers will likely cost more than an intranet application is worth.

Answer (score 2):

For a small team like yours, yes, it might be legitimate.  That doesn't mean they'll like your decision.  And it may depend on who you're talking about - geeks often prefer Chrome or Firefox, while non-technical types often use Internet Explorer because it's built in and the default.

Comment: Most of them are developers like me, which I believe they use Chrome of Firefox indeed

Answer (score 1):

Almost every web site requires some additional time and effort to make properly written code and markup to work in IE. That's why clients get charged more. The extra effort is wasted on your people who wouldn't be using IE anyway. So requiring Chrome or Firefox should be easy and sane.

Answer (score 0):

If your program is worth using, they will *choose* to use a browser that works, you won't have to ask them.

OTOH, you are putting your code out there for others to use. This is a Good Thing, and is how reputations are built. Keep that in mind when you give tools to your co-workers. Make it the absolute best that you can.

Comment: Depending on the skill level of the users, they might not.  They might just complain that it's not working.